# Get Facebook profile pic using 3.0 SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I'm having trouble getting the user's profile pic with the new Facebook SDK. All the answers on here use methods from the old SDK that no longer work.

I've tried using the FBProfilePictureView recommended in Facebook's tutorial, but this picture doesn't get cached and I don't think it can be converted into a UIImage.

Can anyone please provide some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I finally got this using the following:

```
imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; // the image will be loaded in here
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", user.id];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                 timeoutInterval:2];

// Run request asynchronously
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                              delegate:self];
if (!urlConnection)
        NSLog(@"Failed to download picture");
```

Then I used `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` and `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` to put the image together.

Comment: i get  the FB Profile image through NSURLConnection *urlConnection but please  let me know how can i  implement this on UIImageview

Answer (score 9):

Best solution i've found:
I've used UIImage from AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking. It handles redirect and caching so you can fetch profile picture for every user id you have.

```
NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", ((NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *) [self.friends objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]).id];
[friendCell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.jpg"]];
```

Comment: what is self.friends?

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to cache the image. The URL to request the image should be

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?fields=picture", userid];
```

Comment: Worked for me after changing the URL to:
`NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", userid];`

Answer (score 0):

Use the link:

> ```
> https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=picture
> ```

to get the current user's profile picture.

Facebook provides the [Graph API explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) which can come in handy when you want to try queries or to check the returned output.

Here's a link to the [User API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Comment: How would I go from that link to getting it cached in my app?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is related to "self.userPofilePicture.profileID = user.id;".

Then self.userProfilePicture return UIView so just take View and display in it.

Don't forgot add class FBProfilePictureView in Identity Inspector as well as [FBProfilePictureView class] to AppDelegate implementation file.

I hope this will helpful.

Comment: I think this is meant to be used in conjunction with FBLoginView